# C++ - get file path on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos

How would I get the full path to a specific file (on a system running OSX) once the file name is given by the user on a console application? 
Any links or help would be great thanks.

Comment: How is the user giving you the file name? They should be using an [open file dialog](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsopenpanel?language=objc) which will return you the appropriate information.

Comment: @user1118321 through a simple cin user input

Comment: Ah, so this is a console app. You should have specified that in your question.

Comment: @user1118321 yeah sorry forgot to add that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Note that if you ask about `C++ — get file path on Mac OS X`, it is not appropriate to use the C tag — C and C++ are radically different languages in general, and dual-tagging questions annoys the local denizens.

Comment: The chances are that the function you need is [`realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html).  That is a C function from POSIX, but it is declared in `<cstdlib>` (or `<stdlib.h>`) and can readily be used from a C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a filesystem walker. [C++ filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) library will be of use. Start from your initial directory and start iterating. You can use DFS/BFS or your own custom algorithm

Another choice would be to simply see `find` commands source on Linux/Mac.

Edit 1: If you do not want to write a program then use terminal and fire following:

`find / -name <whatever your filename is>`

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. You shouldn't have to search for a file the user specifies. You should get the path from the user like all other apps on macOS do.

Comment: The question says that "How would I get the full path to a specific file (on a system running OSX) once the file name is given by the user? " which implies that file path is not known. And the user might want to write a program for it. How would I know OP's exact requirement.

Comment: Edited the answer. Now OP does not need to write a program so that covers the second possibility. Thanks for pointing out my mistake in assuming that OP wants a program as it was tagged with C++.